# ImportError: No module named extras

Tags: python

While trying to run (Ubuntu) the Zuul tool: http://ci.openstack.org/zuul/zuul.html

I see the following error:

```
zuul@master:~/zuul/zuul$ python cmd/server.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cmd/server.py", line 20, in <module>
    import extras
ImportError: No module named extras
zuul@master:~/zuul/zuul$
```

Uncle Google didn't help.

How to find the missing dependency?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39)  - Zuul seems to be not ported yet to Python3

Comment: There is a class of import errors caused by using Python 3 to run Python 2 code. This isn't it, as you are using Python 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your command prompt and install `extras`  using :

```
$ pip install extras

or

$ easy_install extras
```

Answer (score 1):

The "extras" library suggested in the deleted answer:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/extras/

did the job!